# Undeclared identifier in Verliog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm doing some projects in Verilog and I got some problems with this part of the code.

```
'''
parameter OP_mode = 2'b01;

if(OP_mode == 2'b00)
  parameter k=4;
else if(OP_mode == 2'b01)
  parameter k=8;
      .
      .
      .
reg [k-1:0] inputs;

'''
```

In this case, the compiler gives me the error "Undeclared Identifier: k" How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your parameters inside an unnamed block of code that cannot be referenced from outside ([IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595))

> ###### 27.5 Conditional generate constructs
>
> Generate blocks in conditional generate constructs can be named or unnamed, and they may consist of only one item, which need not be surrounded by `begin-end` keywords. Even if the `begin-end` keywords are absent, it is still a generate block, which, like all generate blocks, comprises a separate scope and a new level of hierarchy when it is instantiated.

```
parameter OP_mode = 2'b01;
if(OP_mode == 2'b00) begin: block
  parameter k=4;
end
else if(OP_mode == 2'b01) begin : block
  parameter k=8;
end
logic [k-1:0] inputs;
```

A better way is using a function call:

```
module top;
  
  parameter OP_mode = 2'b01;
  
  function int f_k;
    if(OP_mode == 2'b00)
       return 4;
    else if(OP_mode == 2'b01) 
       return 8;
    return 0;
  endfunction
  
  parameter k = f_k();
  logic [k-1:0] inputs;
```